# Rails 4 HABTM stops working when I add "multiple true" to collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've googling and trying everything I could think of for the past couple of days to solve a relatively simple (I presume) issue with `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation.

I managed to successful use the HABTM relation to submit a single relation value. Here's the sample code:

Model:

```
class Livre < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many : auteurs
end

class Auteur < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :livres
end
```

Controller:

```
def new
  @livre = Livre.new
  @auteurs = Auteur.all
end

def create
  @livre = Livre.new(livre_params)
  if @livre.save
    redirect_to [:admin, @livre]
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private
  def livre_params
    params.require(:livre).permit(:name, :auteur_ids)
  end
```

View:

```
<% f.label :auteur %><br>
<% f.collection_select(:auteur_ids, @auteurs, :id, :name) %>
```

Posted Params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"mAXUm7MRDgJgCH00VPb9bpgC+y/iOfxBjXSazcthWYs=",
 "livre"=>{"name"=>"sdfsdfd",
 "auteur_ids"=>"3"},
 "commit"=>"Create Livre"}
```

But when I try to add "multiple true" to the view's `collection_select` helper, the (now multiple) relation doesn't get saved anymore. Sample code:

(both Model and Controller unchanged)

View:

```
<% f.label :auteur %><br>
<% f.collection_select(:auteur_ids, @auteurs, :id, :name, {}, {:multiple => true}) %>
```

Posted Params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"mAXUm7MRDgJgCH00VPb9bpgC+y/iOfxBjXSazcthWYs=",
 "livre"=>{"name"=>"sdfsdf",
 "auteur_ids"=>["1",
 "5",
 "3"]},
 "commit"=>"Create Livre"}
```

As you can see, the params for "auteur_ids" is now an array. That's the only difference.

What am I doing wrong?

Just to clarify: both piece of code are able to add a new record to the `livres` db table, but only the 1st code is able to add the appropriate record to the `auteurs_livres` db table. The second one simply does not insert anything into `auteurs_livres`.

(I run on ruby 1.9.3p194 and rails 4.0.1)

Thanks!

---

**Answer**

For the fine folks stuck with the same problem, here's the answer:

Edit your controller and change the permitted parameter from `:auteur_ids` to `{:auteur_ids => []}`

```
params.require(:livre).permit(:name, {:auteur_ids => []})
```

And it now works :)

Comment: Edited to add the posted parameters for both code samples.

Comment: Nice - did you ever consider using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` ?

Comment: @RichPeck No, but I'm going to have a look at it. Thx.

Comment: I was going to write an answer for it, but if you're going to investigate, that's cool! Let me know if you'd like an answer to provide some ideas

Comment: @RichPeck Please contribute. I'm still very new to rails and ruby, any guidance is appreciated :)

Comment: Okay let me see what I can come up with!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the fine folks stuck with the same problem, here's the answer:

Edit your controller and change the permitted parameter from `:auteur_ids` to `{:auteur_ids => []}`

```
params.require(:livre).permit(:name, {:auteur_ids => []})
```

And it now works :)

Answer (score 0):

You worked out the solution because Rails now expects `auteur_ids` to be an array, rather than a single item. This means that instead of just passing a single entity to the model, it will package the params as `[0][1][2]` etc, which is how you can submit your HABTM records now

There is a more Rails way to do this, which is to use [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html). This is going to seem like a lot more work, but it will dry up your system, and also ensure convention over configuration:

**Model**

```
class Livre < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many : auteurs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :auteurs
end

class Auteur < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :livres
end
```

**Controller**

```
def new
  @livre = Livre.new
  @livre.auteurs.build

  @auteurs = Auteur.all
end

def create
  @livre = Livre.new(livre_params)
  if @livre.save
    redirect_to [:admin, @livre]
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private
  def livre_params
    params.require(:livre).permit(:name, auteur_attributes: [:auteur_id])
  end
```

**Form**

```
<%= form_for @livre do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :your_current_vars %>
    <%= f.fields_for :auteurs do |a| %>
        <%= a.collection_select(:auteur_id, @auteurs, :id, :name, {}) %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This will submit the auteur_id for you (and automatically associate the `livre_id` foreign key in the HABTM model. Currently, this will only submit the number of objects which have been built in the `new` action -- so in order to add more items, you'll have to build more

Comment: Quite not working... Rails complains about `undefined method auteur_id` on this line `<%= a.collection_select(:auteur_id, @auteurs, :id, :name, {}) %>`

Comment: Hmmmmm - maybe it could be :id instead?

Comment: That silences the error and let me submit the form, but it won't record the relation. Also, I can only select one value, and if I add the `{:multiple => true}` option back, I can select multiple values but it won't save them either. Somehow, the solution I discovered earlier works better and is easier to understand. I'll just stick to that, but thanks for your help, I really appreciate!

Comment: Yes, that is a small caveat -- to get `accepts_nested_attributes_for` working with multiple elements, there is some wizadry involved. However, it does keep the app super dry & in-line with convention. No problem - if your version is better for you, you should use that! We like to do things the "hard way" so we can learn how they work :)